# Horizontally stretched background aligned bottom and div order

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with some simple(!) code. I managed to have a horizontally stretched background that I aligned to the bottom of the page, but the content DIV that should come above it is hidden underneath the DIV with the background.

My CSS code is:

```
.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1630px;
    background: url(bkg.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: fixed;
}
.postcard {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    height: 465px;
    background-image:url(card.png); 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

And the page code is:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="postcard"></div>
```

I tried setting different z-index values, nothing helped. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` doesn't take effect unless the element has a position property of anything **other** than static. Try `position:relative` on your postcard div.

```
.postcard {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    height: 465px;
    background:red;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/v5xd8bje/)

Answer (score 1):

Give negative z-index to background div

```
.background {
width: 100%;
height: 1630px;
background: url(bkg.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
position: fixed;
z-index:-63
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set a z-index for both classes. And also, the order of your 'background' property is wrong. Check this:

*When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:
background-color
**background-image**
**background-repeat**
background-attachment
**background-position***

```
z-index: -1;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x9uzyjy/)